# Find the flag from a RSA encryption written in C with no modulus

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, rsa, reverse-engineering

So I'm doing a practice Capture The Flag problem, The problem reads:

`I was trying to implement RSA in C but I forgot the modulus. But I think this might be good enough already?`

And then there is this code written in C attached to the question:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int flag1 = <redacted>;
    flag1++;
    unsigned long long int flag2 = <redacted>;
    unsigned long long int ct1 = 1;
    unsigned long long int ct2 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i<65537; i++)
    {
        ct1 = ct1 * flag1;
        ct2 = ct2 * flag2;
    }
    printf("%llu\n",ct1);
    printf("%llu\n",ct2);
}

/*OUTPUT:
7904812928421683021
16220282676865089917
*/
```

I want to get the flag, that is I want to find the values of flag1 and flag2 which outputted ct1(7904812928421683021) and ct2(16220282676865089917) after running in the program. Therefore I want to get the values of flag1 and flag 2 which is indicated by 'redacted' in the program.

I've done some research and found that 65537 is the public key exponent also in the question it states that they forgot the modulus. I've been sitting at this problem for hours now and still couldn't find anything particularly useful. I'm a beginner at cryptography so any help would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone of you could help it would mean a lot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By appearances, `unsigned long long int` is 64 bits in the C implementation being used, so the arithmetic is performed modulo 2<sup>64</sup>.

The loop that multiplies by `flag1` or `flag2` 65537 times computes `flag1`<sup>65537</sup> modulo 2<sup>64</sup> and `flag2`<sup>65537</sup> modulo 2<sup>64</sup>. We are given the results 7904812928421683021 and 16220282676865089917. To find `flag1` and `flag2` prior to the loop, we want to compute the inverse function.

By [a generalization of Fermat’s little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Generalizations), *a*<sup>(*n*)</sup> ≡ 1 mod *n*, where  is [Euler’s totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). This means that exponentiating modulo *n* by (*n*) is the same as exponentiating modulo *n* by 0, which means that exponentiation modulo *n* works modulo (*n*) in the exponent. In other words, *a*<sup>*b*</sup> ≡ *a*<sup>*c*</sup> mod *n* if *b* ≡ *c* mod (*n*).

The way this is useful to us is that when we have *a*<sup>*b*</sup> mod *n*, if we can find a *c* such that *bc* ≡ 1 mod (*n*), then we can compute (*a*<sup>*b*</sup>)<sup>*c*</sup> mod n = *a*<sup>*bc*</sup> mod *n* = *a*<sup>1</sup> mod *n* = *a* mod *n*.

The Wikipedia page for Euler’s totient function tells us (*n*) = *n*•product(1−1/*p* for prime *p*|n). (That product is the multiplication of 1−1/*p* for each prime *p* that divides *n*.) Since our *n* is 2<sup>64</sup>, the only prime that divides it is 2, for which 1−1/2 = ½, so (2<sup>64</sup>) = 2<sup>64</sup>•½ = 2<sup>63</sup>.

Then we need to find the *c* such that *bc* ≡ 1 mod (*n*) for *b* = 65537 and (*n*) = 2<sup>63</sup>. This can be done with the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). However, since we only need to do it once, and the numbers involved are large enough to be awkward to do in common C implementations, we can simply [ask Wolfram Alpha for `65537^-1 mod 2^64`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=65537%5E-1+mod+2%5E63), for which it tells us 9,223,090,566,172,966,913.

Next, we need to be able to raise a number to the power of 9,223,090,566,172,966,913. As this would take too long to do by simple iterative multiplication, we can instead use the algorithm below:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/*  This routine computes x**e modulo 2^64 by multiplying a running product by
    each x**p such that p is a power of two whose corresponding bit is set in
    e.  Thus, if e is 19, which is 10011 in binary, the powers of two
    represented in it are 2^16, 2^1, and 2^0, so we multiply the running
    product by x^(2^0), x^(2^1), and x^(2^16), yielding x^(2^0 + 2^1 + 2^16) =
    x^19.
*/
static uint64_t pow_u64(uint64_t x, uint64_t e)
{
    uint64_t y = 1; //  Initialize running product to 1.
    while (e)       //  Continue while bits remain in exponent.
    {
        if (e & 1)  //  If current bit is set, multiply by power of x.
            y *= x;
        x *= x;     //  Update to next x to a power-of-two.
        e >>= 1;    //  Update e to move next bit into low position.
    }
    return y;
}


static void Do(uint64_t y)
{
    uint64_t c = 9223090566172966913u;
    printf("%" PRIu64 " ^ %" PRIu64 " = %" PRIu64 ".\n", y, c, pow_u64(y, c));
}


int main(void)
{
    Do(7904812928421683021u);
    Do(16220282676865089917u);
}
```

This produces the output:

```
7904812928421683021 ^ 9223090566172966913 = 7380380986431332173.
16220282676865089917 ^ 9223090566172966913 = 5716833052698820989.
```

from which we see the values of `flag1` and `flag2` before the loop are 7,380,380,986,431,332,173 and 5,716,833,052,698,820,989.

Since `flag1` was incremented with `++` after it was initialized by `<redacted>`, we subtract 1 to get the initial value, 7,380,380,986,431,332,172. `flag2` was directly initialized with 5,716,833,052,698,820,989.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort, this actually solved the problem thanks a lot. Have a great day.

Comment: Lovely write-up.